# How to resolve this error "DatabaseConnectionNotDefinedException" on Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal

When setup Drupal 7.26 I got this error :

```
DatabaseConnectionNotDefinedException: The specified database connection is not defined: default in Database::openConnection() (line 1675 of /Library/WebServer/Documents/drupal7/includes/database/database.inc).
```

Does anyone know how to fix this ?

Thanks

Comment: Hope this might help u mate.. https://drupal.org/node/1074098

Answer (score 0):

You might be probably due to the xDebug value that has been set.Try checking the `php.ini` file for `xdebug.show_exception_trace = 1` .

Change that value to

`xdebug.show_exception_trace = 0`.

Xdebug will show a stack trace whenever an exception is raised,even if this exception is actually caught.Now try checking it mate.. :)

This problem has been reported in [here](https://drupal.org/node/1074098)